# Typescript / Angular7 does not allow me to change variable value

Tags: angular, typescript

In my home.page.ts I have defined a variable which its value changes along the way after callback functions are executed. But when I want to use it again, further in my code, it has the default value. Example:

```
export class Home implements OnInit {

test_value = 'a';

constructor(){
//Here I call a function automatically which I expect a 
//callback function to handle the response.
}

myCallbackFunction(result){
   this.test_value = 'b';
}

//Later I push a button to do some action
myButton() {
   console.log(this.test_value); // displays 'a' even I changed
                                 // the value in my callback
}
```

}

How I can assign properly a value?

Comment: how do you pass `myCallbackFunction()`? That may change the `this` inside it. Can you include more of the omitted code from the constructor?

Comment: In other words I suspect this is happening https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-angular7-does-not-allow-me-to-change-variable-value

Comment: William, that is exactly my point. This line solved my problem:  My3rdPartLib.doWithCallback(this.myCallbackFunction.bind(this));

Comment: No one would have known that, I just happened to guess, you should have more complete code examples.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) or a right arrow function to preserve the `this` when passing the callback.

see:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-angular7-does-not-allow-me-to-change-variable-value
lines 24 & 26

Answer (score -2):

Call the function before you print on the console.

```
export class Home implements OnInit {

  test_value = 'a';

  constructor(){
  //Here I call a function automatically which I expect a 
  //callback function to handle the response.
  }

  myCallbackFunction(){
     this.test_value = 'b';
  }

  //Later I push a button to do some action
  myButton() {
     this.myCallbackFunction();
     console.log(this.test_value); // displays 'b' 
  } 
}
```

Comment: I don't think OP wants to call `myCallbackFunction()` when the user clicks a button but when some async action completes.